# Can I make a blank white page on top of a background image?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a background image but want to insert a blank white page on top of it using either html5 or css3. In addition, I would like the page to be able to be adjusted in terms of dimensions.

Comment: You need to add a background to the page. Add a div to the page and with some CSS you will the desired result. I recommend doing a basic HTML and CSS course and trying to do it yourself. If you run into any issues, then ask here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] - Also refer to our [ask] page for instructions on how to improve this question.  Please note: we are not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

From the question description you have provided, I can understand that you need a White Box isnide a Box with an Image as background.

There are many ways to do it, Simple is to create a Div inside Div. Parent Div will have style of background image and child Div will have background color as white and position relative.